# How to manage a dynamic list of tasks with asyncio

Tags: event-handling, python-asyncio, coroutine, nats.io

I have a main class which creates an instance from a list of plugins. In the example below, the 'dhcpv6' plugin is launched and it listens for subscriptions on the 'subject_test_subscribe" subject. As soon as the handler intercepts a new message on this subject, it creates an new asynchronous task by instantiating the classe "Dhcpv6_child().run()" which represents a child of the class Dhcpv6.py. Each child have a timeout to kill the process child. For information, the class plugin definied in **init**.py is an abstract class which allows to load plugins.

I'm not able to dynamically manage the addition of new tasks with asyncio.gather (until the current task is finished, the new task is not executed). The problem is solved with asyncio.create_subprocess_exec but I'd prefer to use the possibilities of asyncio

main.py

```
import argparse
import asyncio
import importlib

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--nats', '-n', nargs="?", type=str, required=True, help="adresse IP du serveur NATS")
parser.add_argument('--plugins', '-p', nargs="+", help="Liste de plugins a utiliser")
args = parser.parse_args()

print("************** main() *****************")
print(f"NATS server IP: {args.nats}")
print(f"List of plugins to load: {args.plugins}")

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for type_plugin in args.plugins:
        try:
            module = importlib.import_module(f'Plugins.{type_plugin}')
            my_class = getattr(module, type_plugin)
            my_instance = my_class(nats=args.nats)
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(my_instance.run()))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Erreur chargement du plugin : ", type_plugin, ":",  e)

    try:
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("timeout main")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.create_task(main())
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Dhcpv6.py

```
import asyncio
import json
import logging
import sys

from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS
from nats.aio.errors import ErrConnectionClosed, ErrTimeout, ErrNoServers
from Plugins import Plugin
from Plugins.Dhcpv6_child import Dhcpv6_child

logger = logging.getLogger("dhcpv6")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class Dhcpv6(Plugin):
    name = "Dhcpv6 plugin"
    subject = "subject_test_subscribe"

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.nats = kwargs.get('nats')
        self.list_task = []
        self.timeout_task = 5
        print("Class dhcpv6 ==> constructor /  nats_ip : {}".format(self.nats))


    async def run(self):
        print("******* run DHCPV6 ***********")
        nc = NATS()
        try:
            await nc.connect("127.0.0.1", verbose=True, pedantic=True)
        except ErrConnectionClosed:
            print(f"La connexion a ete fermee inopinement")
            return
        except ErrTimeout:
            print(f"Le delai imparti a la connexion est depasse")
            return
        except ErrNoServers:
            print(f"Aucun serveur n'a repondu a temps")
            return
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception inattendue: {e}")
            return

        async def plugin_handler(msg):
            print(msg)
            try:
                # Creating and running a new task on demand
                self.list_task.append(asyncio.wait_for(
                    asyncio.create_task(Dhcpv6_child().run()), timeout=self.timeout_task))
                print("append a new task : ", self.list_task)
            except:
                print("Error append new task")

            try:
                print("Running a new task : ", self.list_task)
                await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.gather(*self.list_task), timeout=3600.0)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print("Fin du main : timeout atteint")


        print(f"Subscribing test on : {self.subject}")
        await nc.subscribe(f"{self.subject}", cb=plugin_handler)

        while nc.is_connected:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        await nc.drain()
```

Here is an output screen :

````
************** main() *****************
NATS server IP: 127.0.0.1
List of plugins to load: : ['Dhcpv6']


------------ Load a list of plugins : {Dhcpv6} -------
Class plugin ==> constructor
Class dhcpv6 ==> constructor /  nats_ip : 127.0.0.1

******* run DHCPV6 ***********
INFO:Plugin:Plugin Dhcpv6 plugin loaded
Subscribing test on : subject_test_subscribe
<Msg: subject='subject_test_subscribe' reply='' data='{"query": ...'>

Class CHILD ==> constructor
append a new task :  [<coroutine object wait_for at 0x0000026D0310F040>]
Runnig a new task :  [<coroutine object wait_for at 0x0000026D0310F040>] ```
````

Comment: It looks to me that you are starting all the tasks, but then restricting their order of execution by calling `gather`.  If the tasks are independent, it seems like you could just remove the gather calls and allow each task to run to completion.  You're exiting the program with Control-C anyway, so you have no need to shutdown the various tasks in a coordinated way.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not start all the tasks in Dhcpv6.py. The main.py file starts/loads all the plugins and the goal of Dhcpv6.py is then to create on demand a new task when it is necessary (when a new post is caught on the subject by the coroutine "plugin_handler")

Comment: In the function `plug_in_handler` you create one new task, pass it to the `wait_for` function so you now have an awaitable, and store it in `list_task`.  Then you gather all the awaitables in list_task and wait until all of them are finished.  But all you do at that point is print an error message if you get a timeout.  So remove that gather call.  All your tasks should run then, regardless of where they were created.  If you want to catch TimeoutErrors, register a callback on each task with `add_done_callback` and check the Future for a timeout error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to well understand. If I delete the line that calls the gather, it doesn't work. Will you be able to show me the piece of code with  a add_done_callback ? I would like to move forward on this point

Comment: Please tell me what "it doesn't work" means.  Do you get an error?  What happens?  Just adding a done callback probably isn't going to make it work.

Comment: Here is a new version that creates spots on demand. I created a time counter to stop the task when the timeout is reached (5 seconds in the example below). The check_tasks () function of Dhcpv6_async.py is responsible for stopping the task but I observe that we continue to intercept messages on the subject "inestest.dhcpv6" while the task has been canceled.

Comment: `task = asyncio.create_task(Dhcpv6_child_async(self.nats, self.min_inventory).run())
            self.list_task.append(task)
            await asyncio.wait(self.list_task)`

Comment: `async def check_tasks():
    if len(self.lb_name) > 0:
        for i, task in enumerate(self.list_task):
            if self.date_end[i] <= datetime.now():
                try:
                    task.cancel()
                    self.list_task.remove(self.list_task[i])
                except asyncio.CancelledError:
                    print('caught error from cancelled task')
                except:
                    raise Exception("Error stop process (timeout or returncode)")  `

Comment: Sorry for code indentation ...

Comment: I think StackOverflow will allow you to answer your own question.  I read once that this is actually encouraged, because then other developers can see it and benefit from it.  The answer format also lets you solve the indentation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Cornelius and thank for yours advices. You're right, asyncio.create_task() allows to create task on demand. If I want to process one task after another, we need to add asyncio.wait(self.list_task) but it's not my purpose. Here is how i create a new child in "Dhcpv6.py". For information, the main() routine, called by asyncio.create_task(), is imported from the child script "Dhcpv6_child.py" :

```
        if not mac in self.list_mac:
            self.list_task.append(asyncio.create_task(main(self.nats,
                                            self.min_inventory['name'],
                                            self.min_inventory,
                                            str(datetime.now()),
                                            str(datetime.now() + self.timeout))))
            self.date_start.append(datetime.now())
            self.date_end.append(datetime.now() + self.timeout)
            self.lb_name.append(self.min_inventory['name'])
            self.list_mac.append(mac)
            # logger.info(f"{self.lb_name} {task.get_name()} created")
            await nc.subscribe(f"call.dhcpv6.{self.min_inventory['name']}", cb=cancel_tasks)
        else :
            logger.warning(f"[{__name__}] Task adress %s already in list_mac", mac)
```

Finally, as I have problems to correctly manage the list of tasks, I associated a time counter for each child (as described above in the main routine). When a task is finished, the child send a message to the parent which updates the current task list.